# From Stackexchange to FAQ

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way to get an easy extract of all of the questions on the FAQ so that the best ones can be added to the official Tor FAQ for example in CSV or some other basic format?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a api query here: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts
This will output posts to json format that can be converted to other formats. The output is very limited so I will need to write a script to incrementally query the server to output everything for the past 12 months.